# UnitTest fails because of appends property (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, phpunit

I have the model Products, which has the protected property $appends = ['category_name']. This category name is being set by an getCategoryNameAttribute function. Accessing the endpoint in my browser works as expected, however testing this endpoint via unit tests crashes the test sequence.

```
class Product extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'products';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'category_id', 'durability_id'
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        'category_name'
    ];

    public function getCategoryNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->category->name;
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
    }

}
```

The endpoint I'm testings shows a list of all products ( Product::all() ). When I remove the appends property or return a static value like 1 or 'one', the test passes.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ProductTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    public function test_index_shows_a_list()
    {
        $this->visit('/api/v1/products');
    }
}
```

**Error**:
Starting test 'ProductTest::test_index_shows_a_list'.
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php on line 72

I'm not sure what the problem is as I'm new to unit-testing, but it probably has something to do with using a laravel relation.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have setup your TestCase

```
public function __construct()
{
   parent::setup();
}
```

This error message comes specifically from the XDebug extension.

make sure that you have increase your maximum functions nesting via xdebug

open `/etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini` and  add `xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200`

Comment: I have another testcase that tests a class without the $appends property. This sequence runs fine. Adding the setUp() in the construct of the failing test sequence produces another error: "ReflectionException: Class config does not exist"

Comment: make sure that you have increase your maximum functions nesting via xdebug. open `/etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini` and add `xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200`